# [emacs][gdb customization] How to display source-buffer in one window?

Tags: debugging, emacs, gdb, customization

I have customized gdb windows in emacs. After it during debugging new source code opens in different windows. I'd like to see source code only in one window. My gdb customization is:

```
;     _____________________________________________________________________________________
;    |                                          |                                          |
;    |              BREAKPOINTS                 |                                          |
;    |__________________________________________|                                          |
;    |                                          |                                          |
;    |                 STACK                    |                                          |
;    |__________________________________________|                                          |
;    |                                          |                                          |
;    |                                          |                                          |
;    |                 LOCALS                   |                                          |
;    |                                          |                SOURCE CODE               |
;    |__________________________________________|                                          |
;    |                                          |                                          |
;    |                                          |                                          |
;    |                                          |                                          |
;    |                                          |                                          |
;    |                                          |                                          |
;    |                                          |                                          |
;    |                  GDB                     |                                          |
;    |                                          |__________________________________________|
;    |                                          |                                          |
;    |                                          |                                          |
;    |                                          |                    I/O                   |
;    |                                          |                                          |
;    |__________________________________________|__________________________________________|

(require 'gud)

; invoke
(global-set-key [f8] 'gdb)

; GDB layout
(defadvice gdb-setup-windows (after activate)
  (gdb-setup-my-windows)
)

(defun gdb-setup-my-windows ()
  (set-window-dedicated-p (selected-window) nil)
  (switch-to-buffer gud-comint-buffer)
  (delete-other-windows)
  (let
    ((win0 (selected-window))             ; breakpoints
     (win1 (split-window-horizontally
         (floor (* 0.5 (window-width)))))   ; source + i/o
     (win2 (split-window-vertically
         (floor (* 0.5 (window-body-height))))) ; gdb
     (win3 (split-window-vertically
        (floor (* 0.5 (window-body-height))))) ; locals
     (win4 (split-window-vertically
         (floor (* 0.6 (window-body-height))))) ; stack
    )
    (select-window win1)
    ; configurating right window
    (let
    ((winSrc (selected-window)) ; source
     (winIO (split-window-vertically (floor (* 0.9 (window-body-height))))) ; I/O
     )
      (set-window-buffer winIO (gdb-get-buffer-create 'gdb-inferior-io))
      (set-window-buffer
    winSrc
    (if gud-last-last-frame
     (gud-find-file (car gud-last-last-frame))
      (if gdb-main-file
       (gud-find-file gdb-main-file)
     (list-buffers-noselect))))
      (setq gdb-source-window winSrc)
      (set-window-dedicated-p winIO t)
   )

    (set-window-buffer win0 (gdb-get-buffer-create 'gdb-breakpoints-buffer))
    (set-window-buffer win3 (gdb-get-buffer-create 'gdb-locals-buffer))
    (set-window-buffer win4 (gdb-get-buffer-create 'gdb-stack-buffer))
    (select-window win2)
  )
)

; GDB variables
(setq gdb-many-windows t)
(setq gdb-show-main t)
(setq gdb-show-changed-values t)
(setq gdb-use-colon-colon-notation t)
(setq gdb-use-separate-io-buffer nil)
(setq gdb-delete-out-of-scope t)
(setq gdb-speedbar-auto-raise t)
```

The main screen is:
[gdb screen after start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHZLZ.png)

But when I started debugging then next source file opens in another window. See example bellow:
[New source code  in gdb window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4G0Hy.png)

The example of application to reproduce is:

*main.cpp*

```
#include "classB.h"

int main()
{
  B *b = 0;
  b = new B();
  return 0;
}
```

*classA.h*

```
#ifndef CLASS_A_H
#define CLASS_A_H

class A
{
public:
  A();
};

#endif
```

*classA.cpp*

```
#include "classA.h"
#include <iostream>

A::A()
{
  std::cout << "Constructor A" << std::endl;
}
```

*classB.h*

```
#ifndef CLASS_B_H
#define CLASS_B_H

#include "classA.h"

class B : public A
{
public:
  B();
};

#endif
```

*classB.cpp*

```
#include "classB.h"
#include <iostream>

B::B() : A()
{
  std::cout << "Constructor B" << std::endl;
}
```

*Makefile*

```
SOURCES=main.cpp classA.cpp classB.cpp
TARGET=test
CXX_FLAGS=-g

.PHONY: all

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(SOURCES)
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) $^ -o $@

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -vf $(TARGET)
```

Step to reproduce:

1. Run emacs
2. M-x gdb
3. gdb -i=mi test
4. In gdb command window run: start
5. run: next
6. run: step

My environment is: Ubuntu14.04, gdb - 7.7.1, emacs - 25.1.1.

I tried to use ***set-window-dedicated-p***. But this is not solution for my problem.
I'm new in emacs, help me please, what is wrong in my configuration?

Comment: sorry for going off topic, but what theme are you using for `linum` and buffer separators ?

Comment: I'd suggest removing the [tags] from your title as SO has tags as part of the question already.

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan, I'm using idea-darkula-theme.

Answer (score 0):

`display-buffer-alist` lets you control in which windows new buffers are displayed. You start by registering a function pointer inside it

```
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
         (cons 'cdb-source-code-buffer-p
           (cons 'display-source-code-buffer nil)))
```

then implement the function that selects a window, for example

```
(defun cdb-source-code-buffer-p (bufName action)
  "Return whether BUFNAME is a source code buffer."
  (let ((buf (get-buffer bufName)))
    (and buf
     (with-current-buffer buf
       (derived-mode-p buf 'c++-mode 'c-mode 'csharp-mode 'nxml-mode)))))

(defun display-source-code-buffer (sourceBuf alist)
  "Find a window with source code and set sourceBuf inside it."
  (let* ((curbuf (current-buffer))
     (wincurbuf (get-buffer-window curbuf))
     (win (if (and wincurbuf
               (derived-mode-p sourceBuf 'c++-mode 'c-mode 'nxml-mode)
               (derived-mode-p (current-buffer) 'c++-mode 'c-mode 'nxml-mode))
          wincurbuf
        (get-window-with-predicate
         (lambda (window)
           (let ((bufName (buffer-name (window-buffer window))))
             (or (cdb-source-code-buffer-p bufName nil)
             (assoc bufName display-buffer-alist)
             ))))))) ;; derived-mode-p doesn't work inside this, don't know why...
    (set-window-buffer win sourceBuf)
    win))
```

`cdb-source-code-buffer-p` select source code buffers, for which `display-source-code-buffer` is called, that returns the window you want.

Comment: Sorry I'm new in Emacs and I don't understand how should I use it in my file with gdb configuration. Could you please explain?
I added the functions to my config file and tried to call display-source-code-buffer function, but it's not working.

Comment: @EgorCh. Please read the documentation of `display-buffer-alist`, by typing `M-x describe-variable` then `display-buffer-alist`. There you will learn that you do not call `display-source-code-buffer` yourself, Emacs calls it for you when it needs to display a source code buffer. For a general introduction to Emacs lisp, read  [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/elisp.html)

Comment: Is it possible to somehow only add this to the `display-buffer-alist` callback for the duration of when gdb mode is active in emacs, somehow? This solves the issue, but affects any code such as `find-file-other-window`, for example.

Comment: @sonictk in `cdb-source-code-buffer-p` you can test whether gdb is active

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler version that worked for me.  It takes advantage of the fact that by default, the GUD window and IO window are dedicated.  So it's sufficient to just ask display-buffer to an existing window (since there is only one choice available).

```
;; Ensure that all source files are opened in the same window when gdb                                                                                                  
;; is running.                                                                                                                                                          
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
         (cons 'gdb-source-code-buffer-p
           (cons 'display-buffer-use-some-window nil)))

(defun gdb-source-code-buffer-p (bufName action)
  "Return whether BUFNAME is a source code buffer and gdb is running."
  (let ((buf (get-buffer bufName)))
    (and buf
         (eq gud-minor-mode 'gdbmi)
         (with-current-buffer buf
           (derived-mode-p buf 'c++-mode 'c-mode)))))
```